# Cannot Produce PDFs in Local System

Tags: java, pdf, xsl-fo, buildpath

I'm getting the following error when I try to produce a PDF (XSL:FO generated) in my local server:

> Error 500: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.sun.media.jai.codec.FileCacheSeekableStream

Given that this error doesn't show up on our DEV server, or any other server that this application deploys to, I'm thinking the issue is probably a missing .jar file in my build path.

Knowing that we use FOP (Version 1.0, I believe), code in JAVA, and are using XSL:FO to format our documents, what .jar files might I be missing from my build path?

Comment: In order to know the precise version of FOP you are using, you can run `fop -version`.

Comment: @lfurini This would be useful, but I'm not sure what you mean.  From where?  And against what?  I assume you're talking about a command line based on the format of your suggestion, but at a loss on whether to run it against my Java project, a compiled EAR file, or the FOP.jar itself, to say nothing of how to reference it (replace 'fop' with the exact directory of my fop.jar file in a command line?)

Comment: What Java is being used in each of the two servers? I will bet they are different (like JDK on your dev environment and JRE in the other). The error is that you are missing the classes for processing streams in images (like GIF) ... depending on what Java you are using, they may have been in the JDK or had to be included separately.

Comment: I was indeed referring to the bash script FOP distributions include in the topmost folder (there is a `fop.bat` for windows and `fop` for *nix operating systems); these scripts perform some checks, set options and environment variables and finally call `java -jar fop.jar` (with all the needed parameters ...). **But**, now I think of it, there is an easier way to check the version: in the created PDF files, FOP sets the **creator** property to _Apache FOP Version X.Y_.